# Implement Strategy pattern with Guice DI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, strategy-pattern

I am very new in `Guice DI`. I am trying to implement a `Strategy` pattern with `Guice`. But I am confused on, How to inject different types of **Strategy Implementations** in the `Context` class through `Guice DI`. Can any expert help me on this. Following are my codes till now.

**The Strategy Pattern**

```
public interface MetricCollectorStrategy {
    List<String> collect(final Context context);
}

public class AMetricCollector implements MetricCollectorStrategy {
 @Override
 public List<String> collect(final Context context) {
    List<String> aMetricList = construct A metric list by some business logic....
    return aMetricList;
 }
}


public class BMetricCollector implements MetricCollectorStrategy {
 @Override
 public List<String> collect(final Context context) {
    List<String> bMetricList = construct B metric list by some business logic....
    return bMetricList;
 }
}


@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Inject)
public class MetricPublisher {

    // This has a method to publish metric
    private final MetricsHelper metricsHelper;
    private final MetricCollectorStrategy metricCollectorStrategy;

 
    public void collectAndPublishMetric(Context context) {
        metricsHelper.emitCollectedCountMetricList(metricCollectorStrategy.collect(context));
    }
}
```

Till then it's fine. But how to create and inject these 2 types of `MetricCollector` in the client:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Inject)
public class Client{
    
  // Some dummy code to simulate the current code
  private final ExistingDependency_1 existingDependency_1;

  private final ExistingDependency_2 existingDependency_2;

  private final ExistingDependency_3 existingDependency_2;


  // Now how to create the metricCollectors here

  AMetricCollector aMetricCollector;
  BMetricCollector bMetricCollector;

  public void someMethod(Context context){


      if(condition){
        aMetricCollector.collectAndPublishMetric(context);
      }else{
        bMetricCollector.collectAndPublishMetric(context);
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the spot where you say

> `// Now how to create the metricCollectors here`

is not where you should actually *create* the metricCollectors. That's the point of Dependency Injection, you inject your dependencies rather than constructing them.

You should instead have a constructor where you receive those dependencies and your DI framework should create them.